# Взаимодействие C# и Java

Tags: java, c#, android, windows

Мне нужно реализовать сетевое взаимодействие приложений на Android (Java) и Windows (C#). Я испытываю трудности с написанием серилизатора на разных языках чтобы они корректно работали друг с другом.

Вопрос: если я напишу серилизатор на одном из этих языков. Могу ли я на C# вызвать функции из Java класса (Как через DllImport). Или наоборот в Java вызвать функции из dll файла написанного на C#?

Comment: Может быть вам и не нужен вовсе сериализатор и возможность напрямую вызывать код на C# из Java? Может вам достаточно будет просто сделать на C# API, которое будет выдавать данные в виде JSON, которые вы будете в Java любым из множества готовых решений преобразовывать в Java классы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В 90-е, да и в начале 2000-х идея удалённого вызова методов ещё имела право на существование. Было разработано несколько технологий, например, веб-сервисы, RPC, SOAP. С помощью SOAP, например, можно обращаться к методам сервера, написанного на другом языке. Не буду углубляться в теорию потому что к счастью, этот бред остался (почти) в истории. Если будет желание - можно посмотреть, как мучились разработчики в то время: https://github.com/LeonisX/soap-examples

Сейчас всё делается проще. Есть сервер, есть клиенты. У сервера есть несколько ендпоинтов, обращаясь к которым клиенты получают/отправляют данные. Современные сервера стараются придерживаться [REST архитектуры,](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST) хотя, это уже дело вкуса. Можно публиковать такие ендпоинты, какие удобно видеть. REST это всего лишь рекомендация.

Так вот. Для передачи данных можно использовать любые форматы. В тренде сейчас JSON. Так же много лет используется XML, но он несколько сложнее в использовании (с точки зрения программиста Java). Но тут опять же, что передавать или получать. Например:

Ендпоинт:

```
GET /user/12
```

Ответ:

```
   "firstName": "Иван",
   "lastName": "Иванов",
   "address": {
       "streetAddress": "Московское ш., 101, кв.101",
       "city": "Ленинград",
       "postalCode": "101101"
   },
   "phoneNumbers": [
       "812 123-1234",
       "916 123-4567"
   ]
}
```

Всё просто и здорово. В XML ответ будет более громоздким. Можно так же передавать просто текст, бинарные данные, всё зависит от конкретного случая. А можно от клиента и ничего не передавать, если удастся уместить параметры запроса в URL.

***То есть, предлагаю пойти по клиент-серверному пути. Сервер на C# выставляет ендпоинты, клиенты Android с ними взаимодействуют.***

Есть и другие решения. Например, приложение C# может слушать определённый порт сервера. Но это уже низкоуровневая работа, и в двух строках не объяснишь.